# How to launch specific LiveChannels channel from home screen programpreview on android-tv

Tags: android, android-tv

If you are at all familiar with tv-input-framework and livechannels and the home channel program previews then I have a question for you. I am trying to create a homescreen channel that will list recently watched live channels through our tv-input-service. I can list them just fine but launching the preview programs into the specified "live channel" is seemingly impossible. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
    Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.tv");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(TvContract.buildChannelUri(channel.getId()));
```

Comment: What makes you think the above code doesn't work?  Did you get an error message?  If so, please post the error and any stack trace you observed.

Comment: there is no error, it just launches live channels app to the previously watched channel, not the one that was selected in the home screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through LiveChannel's source I found the answer

```
static long addPreviewProgram(Context context, long homeChannelId, Uri liveChannelUri){
    PreviewProgram.Builder builder = new PreviewProgram.Builder();

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.tv", "com.android.tv.MainActivity"));
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(liveChannelUri);

    builder.setChannelId(homeChannelId)
            .setType(PreviewPrograms.TYPE_CLIP)
            .setIntent(intent);

    Uri programUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(PreviewPrograms.CONTENT_URI, builder.build().toContentValues());

    return ContentUris.parseId(programUri);

}
```

The intent action and channel set happens in LiveChannel's MainActivity but MainActivity isn't the launcher activity so you have to specify it as the activity that you want to launch into. Must set action as Intent.ACTION_VIEW or the channel will never be set.